# I'm trying to set my cors origins value to a list of trusted subdomains, using node.js and javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, cors

Something is off with my setup.  I'm wondering if it is how I defined my list of allowed origins in my .env file.

In my .env file i have a list of trusted subdomains:

```
// .env file
ALLOWED_ORIGINS=http://localhost:3001, http://localhost:3000, https://wwww.site1.com, https://www.site2.com
```

in my server.ts file I am trying to set origins to the value from my .env file, see the line **origins: allowedOrigins**.  It was previously set to **origins: ['*']**

```
// server.ts file

export default createServer = (container) => {
  const env = process.env.NODE_ENV
  const allowedOrigins = process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGINS || ''

  const cors = Cors({
    origins: allowedOrigins,
    allowedHeaders: [
      'access-control-allow-origin',
      'authorization',
      'Pragma',
      'contact',
    ],
    exposeHeaders: []
  })
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is "off"? Did you check what value you're actually setting origins to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to split them by comma

```
const allowedOrigins = process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGINS.split(",") || '';
```

Also,

I believe it is just **origin** and not **origins**

For the below, allowedOrigins must be an array. so you just map and return an array

```
const allowedOrigins = process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGINS.split(',').map(origin=>origin);

const cors = Cors({
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
        allowedOrigins.includes(origin) ? callback(null, true) : callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    },
    allowedHeaders: [
      'access-control-allow-origin',
      'authorization',
      'Pragma',
      'contact',
    ],
    exposeHeaders: []
  })
}
```

Ref:- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 3):

I checked the [cors npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options), the `origins` option does **not** accept multiple origins in a comma-separated string. It accepts an **array** instead.

You can split your environment variable by "," to have the desired format. In the code below, I added the `.trim()` method to cut down unnecessaries spaces in the string.

```
// server.ts file

export default createServer = (container) => {
  const env = process.env.NODE_ENV
  const allowedOrigins = process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGINS || ''
  const allowedOriginsArray = allowedOrigins.split(",").map(item => item.trim());

  const cors = Cors({
    origins: allowedOriginsArray,
    allowedHeaders: [
      'access-control-allow-origin',
      'authorization',
      'Pragma',
      'contact',
    ],
    exposeHeaders: []
  })
}
```